# Is there a way to merge multiple range into a single range for sheets appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to merge 2 ranges(WITH values) into 1 range(empty)

I was trying to do it like this

```
function regressionMaker(){

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var name = activeSheet.getRange ("E2:E").getValues();
  var title = activeSheet.getRange ("F2:F").getValues();

  var x = " - ";

  activeSheet.getRange("T2:T").setValues(name + x + title);
}
```

All I get is an error saying **"Cannot find method setValues(string)"**

I was expecting of having a result of

Column 1     Column 2              Column3

Apple            Banana                 Apple - Banana

**Updates**

```
  var name = activeSheet.getRange ("E2:E").getValues();
  var title = activeSheet.getRange ("F2:F").getValues();


  var merged = name.map(

    function(nameValues,rowIndex){

    var titleValues = title[rowIndex];
    return [nameValues[0] + ' - ' + titleValues[0]];
    }
  );

  activeSheet.getRange("V2:V").setValues(merged);
```

Tho nothing happened :(

Comment: Also, you know you can do this in Google Sheets with a formula. For example, if you put `=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A & " - " & B2:B)` in C2....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1.1**

You are trying to pass a `String` to the `setValues()` method which can only be passed a two-dimensional `Array` (that is, Array of Arrays). Error message states just that: "there is no method `setValues()` such that it accepts `String` as an argument".

**Problem 1.2**

`getValues()` method yields an Array of Arrays as well, so your `names` and `title` variables actually contain `[['Apple']]` and `[['Banana']]` respectively (assuming your ranges include values only).

**Problem 1.3**

JavaScript is *dynamically typed*, so it performs type coercion for you and it often leads to issues like you have. In the case of `+`, if any argument is of type `String`, JS will try to coerce the other one to a `String` (e.g. `'11' + 2 = '112'`).

**Solution**

The abovementioned problems should lead you to an algorithm: "map each row of data in column 1 to a column 2 such that the result is a string concatenation of both values separated by a hyphen with two whitespaces".

**Application**

Since you do a one-column merge, all you need is to get the first value from column 1, the first value from column 2, concatenate them and wrap into an Array representing new cell.

```
var merged = names.map(function(nameValues,rowIndex){
  var titleValues = titles[rowIndex];
  return [nameValues[0] + ' - ' + titleValues[0]];
});
```

Comment: I tried to do this and end up having no errors which is good, but as I tried to setValues(merged); nothing printed

Comment: Hi, @JakeHardy - just to make sure - I used the `names` and `titles` variable names (misread that yours are called `name` and `title`, my bad) - have you changed the naming? Although, not doing that should've caused an error. Are you using this script as a custom function or a script?

Comment: @JakeHardy - could you please make an update to your question so as I could see the how you implemented the solution?

Comment: Thanks, @JakeHardy! Hm, then there is still a question of whether the script is a custom function or a macros / bound script. If it is the second case, please, log `name` and `value` with `Logger.log()` or `console.log()` and inpect their values - are they 2D arrays with values?

Comment: Actually it's a custom function, and when i used the logs, it printed different results as on what I expected. Apparently your code works, and it fixed my problem. It's just that I literally have another sheet first before the one i was editing and I thought using  ```.getActiveSheet()``` gets the sheet you are currently on. Well it was the first sheet and i'm on the second sheet. so I used ```.getSheetByName()``` and it worked. Thanks for the patience o7, these things are new to me.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've found the source of the problem! Strange, though, that you can use `setValues` if this is a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) - probably you refer to a document-bound script. I've seen the issue you've described before - in certain use cases `getActiveSheet` returns the first sheet (e.g. when you try to invoke it without user interaction via script), thus `getSheetByName()` and `getSheetById()` or `getSheets()` + index-based iteration are solutions of choice.
Happy coding and don't hesitate to ask if any help needed)